# how to cover catch in test class for a scheduler class

Tags: apex, unit-test, scheduled-apex

This is my scheduler class. I am not able to cover  `System.abortJob(ctx.getTriggerId())`
My batch is updating values on the account object

```
global class Tets_outage_batchScheduler implements Schedulable{  
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx){     
        try{  
            List<AsyncApexJob> lstApexJob = [SELECT id from AsyncApexJob Where ApexClassID IN (SELECT id FROM ApexClass WHERE Name = 'Esc_outage_batch') AND (Status IN ('Queued','Processing','Preparing','Holding'))Limit 1 ];                   
            if(lstApexJob.isempty()){                          
                Test_outage_batch b = new Test_outage_batch();
                 database.executebatch(outagebatch,Integer.valueOf(System.Label.batch_size));
            }
            if(!lstApexJob.isempty()) { 
                System.abortJob(ctx.getTriggerId()); 
            }
        }    
        catch(exception ex){  System.abortJob(ctx.getTriggerId()); }
    }        
}
```

Comment: What catchable exception do you expect to be caught by this `catch` block?

Comment: In other words, if you can't think of what exception could be thrown in your `try` block, then that's a sign that you should remove the try/catch. Try/catch is a tool with a specific purpose, and you should be able to answer "what exception do I expect, and why am I catching this exception?". Sprinkling try/catch blocks in your code without purpose leads to code that's difficult to test and maintain. Also keep in mind that things like governor limit exceptions cannot be caught.

Comment: agree 100% w/ David and Derek; also, the general solution for testing difficult-to-mock exceptions is to wrap the code in a _service_ layer object and, at testtime, inject a mock service object that throws an exception